# How to call a dart function from a function written in C / C ++?

Tags: c++, c, dart

The article *https://www.dartlang.org/articles/server/native-extensions* describes how to use functions written in ***C/C++*** in ***dart*** modules. Both the synchronous and asynchronous way of calling C/C++ functions work, and that's very well. However, there is a question: is it possible to transfer a ***pointer to a function written in dart*** into module written in ***C/C++*** and use this pointer as a ***callback function***? I.e. to call this function from a module in C/C++ and pass some parameters to it as these parameters changes. Create, suppose a ***listener*** in the ***C/C++*** module and subscribe to it in ***dart***? Is there a similar method of communication in ***dart***? Maybe there are some other ways to communicate and transfer data between ***dart*** and ***C/C++***? Maybe something completely exotic like ***EventBus***?

Comment: You want to *embed* the Dart VM into your C++ code. How to do that (or even if it is possible)  is a different question

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - I don't think he's trying to invoke Dart from a C++ program. Rather, he's got a Dart program that invokes a native extension. And he wants the native extension in C++ to call back into the Dart program.

Comment: @selbie - Your clarification is correct. I really mean how to call the dart function from the extension.